# Inequality involving probabilities

Tags: calculus, probability, inequality

While working on stochastics processes, I have found the following inequality, which I have not been able to proof:

Let $h>l>1$ and $0\leqslant p\leqslant 1$ (probability). Then

$$ph\log\left(\frac{h}{ph+(1-p)l}\right)+(1-p)l\log\left(\frac{l}{ph+(1-p)l}\right)\geqslant 0$$

**How may be proved this inequality?** Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: Use the convexity of $x \log x$.

Comment: I suppose it must be useful... But at this very moment I do not see which $x$ should I take... perhaps the values $x_1=h/(ph+(1-p)l)$ and $x_2=p/(ph+(1-p)l)$? But it does not match with the values multiplying the logarithms... Could you help me a bit further? Thanks

Comment: It does, note your $x_2$ needs $l$ in the numerator, not $p$. Divide your expression by $ph+(1-p)l$. And note that $px_1+(1-p)x_2=1$.

Comment: Ok, I have just caught it! Let $f(x)=x\log(x)$. Then, by the convexity, $pf(x_1)+(1-p)f(x_2)\geqslant f(px_1+(1-p)x_2)=f(1)=0$. Thank you very much!